# data.table passing in a `by` expression in non interactive way

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use several expressions in `by` of data.table (not just column names) in a dynamic way

This is what I want to do:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT[, mean(y), by = .(over4 = v > 4)]
```

I thought I might be able to pass in a character vector with the expressions, but this doesn't work:

```
by_expression = c("over4" = "v > 4")
DT[, mean(y), by = by_expression]
```

Is there a way to pass in expressions in a dynamic way?

I have this work around, but this is a bit of work if there are several by conditions, and then wants tidying up after doing the by operation later

```
DT[, condition := v > 4, ]
DT[, mean(y), by = condition]
```

Comment: You can always use bquote and eval. Obviously, you should pass an actual expression (created with quote) instead of a character vector.

Comment: Yes, am aware of the eval(quote approach but it's kind of messy. I'm wondering if there is a simpler way in data.table syntax that I've overlooked ...

Comment: This seems to work without `eval`. Doesn't look messy, does it? `by_expression = quote(list(over4 = v > 4)) ; DT[, mean(y), by = by_expression]`

Comment: Or `quote(.(over4 = v > 4))` (same)

Comment: that's great - should put that as an answer and ill upvote

Comment: I will and if @Roland posts theirs I'll withdraw mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `quote`d expression:

```
by_expression = quote(.(over4 = v > 4))
DT[, mean(y), by = by_expression]

#    over4   V1
# 1: FALSE 2.75
# 2:  TRUE 3.80
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
by_expression <- c("over4" = "v > 4",
                   "over2" = "v > 2")
```

```
lapply(by_expression, function(ex) DT[, mean(y), by = .(eval(parse(text = ex)))])
```

Result:

```
$over4
   parse   V1
1: FALSE 2.75
2:  TRUE 3.80

$over2
   parse       V1
1: FALSE 2.000000
2:  TRUE 3.714286
```